# Can ground coffee beans or instant coffee be used for b'samim during Havdalah?

Tags: halacha, havdalah, spices

Can instant coffee and fresh ground coffee be used for b'samim (spices) during Havdalah?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question! Short answer: yes, but probably only freshly-ground beans.

[Mishna Brurah 216.16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&pgnum=243) writes, concerning the blessings on spices anytime you smell them during the week:

> כתבו האחרונים המריח בקאוו"י כתושה והיא חמה שריחה נודף ואדם נהנה מאותו ריח צריך לברך ברכת אשר נתן וכו':‏
>
> The late authorities wrote that one who smells ground coffee, if it is warm so its smell is strong, and one enjoys that smell, he must recite the blessing of *Who gave fragrance to fruit.*

Certainly if freshly ground, that's *warm so its smell is strong*; I'm not sure that would apply to a jar of instant coffee that's been sitting on your shelf for a year. (Unless he simply means this doesn't apply if the coffee is in the freezer -- or you live someplace where the room temperature is 40 degrees Fahrenheit?)

Flip back a page in the Mishna Brurah and you'll see that on fragrant fruits, Sephardim say the bracha in the present tense: *hanoten re'ach tov bapeirot* ("bless you God our Almighty sovereign of the Universe, **who gives** fruits their fragrance"), while Ashkenazim say it in the past tense: *asher natan re'ach tov bapeirot* ("**who gave fruits their fragrance**").

Okay, so that covers if I smell coffee on a Tuesday morning. How about for Havdalah?

Let's hop over to the laws of Havdalah. Sephardic practice is to make whichever blessing is suitable to this particular spice; Ashkenazic practice is to say the all-purpose "borei minei besamim" on anything, to avoid confusing people. The Mishna Brurah recommends as an extra stringency to therefore purposely pick something whose weekday blessing is always "minei besamim."

**Conclusion**: That would leave Ashkenazim with a very slight preference to use cloves, musk, or potpourri rather than coffee, but it would still certainly be acceptable, and its bracha during Havdalah would be the usual *borei minei besamim.* A Sephardic Jew using coffee for Havdalah would recite *hanotein rei'ach tov bapeirot*.

Comment: Cloves are _Minei Vesamim_? Don't they grow on a tree and are edible?

Comment: @DoubleAA very good question! See OC216: Sephardim say they're "fruit" and we're done. Some Ashkenazim are concerned that because they're immature, the bracha should be "tree" and not "fruit" ... and to resolve that, some later Achronim say to use the catch-all "minei" ... which the Mishna Brurah then says to use *that* to solve the Ashkenazi conundrum of "people-will-get-confused-during-Havdalah."

Comment: @DoubleAA and thanks for catching that properly the bracha is "vesamim" with a veis; I was concerned that would confuse people in the answer here.

Comment: The whole cloves discussion is not one that leaves me super-proud to be an Ashkenazi, quite frankly ...

Comment: I think you may have oversimplified the clove situation http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=6897

Comment: What does warm have to do with ground? He might mean warm from the roasting process.

Comment: @user6591 the precise wording: "Coffee that is ground, and it is warm so its smell spreads." It didn't say "roasted", it says it is warm right now. You'll get the most scent going through the air if the coffee beans are a.) ground, and b.) warm (molecules move faster).

Comment: I said might. Cham can also mean hot. I've never warmed freshly ground beans to see if they smell any better. I can only imagine roasted beans do have a good smell whether or not they are ground. I'll ask my friend if he has any insight. He's in the business.

Comment: @user6591 if they're freshly-ground, they will be warm from the friction! (Go to any grinder at any supermarket.)

Comment: If that's true that would be a nafka mina. My grinders don't warm up the beans. Burr or blade grinders.